# What is httpBasic method in spring security?

Tags: spring-security

I override `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in SampleSecurityConfig Class like this

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().and().httpBasic();
}
```

If i don't use `httpBasic` method, it seems no problem occurred.

what does `httpBasic` method exactly do?

Comment: May i ask, when using browser to access your application, does your application returns a form login page, or does it trigger your browser to pop up a BASIC authentication dialog box?   I ask this, cos i saw your configuration with both .formLogin and .httpBasic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling this method on `HttpSecurity` will enable [Http Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for your application with some "reasonable" defaults.

It will return a [HttpBasicConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HttpBasicConfigurer.html) for further customization.

You can test this by curl and passing a header like `Authorization: Basic bzFbdGfmZrptWY30YQ==` but base64 encoding a valid username/password combination.

Documentation for [httpBasic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#httpBasic--)

Answer (score 7):

##### What are we saying by calling httpBasic() ?

- When `httpBasic()` is called, we are telling Spring to authenticate the request using the values passed by the `Authorization` request header. If the request is not authenticated you will get a returned status of `401`  and a error message of `Unauthorized`

##### What is actually happening when httpBasic() is called ?

- By calling `httpBasic()`, an instance of the [BasicAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html) is added to the filter chain. The BasicAuthenticationFilter will then proceed with trying to authenticate the request in the typical Spring Security fashion. If authentication is successful, the resulting Authentication object will be placed into the SecurityContextHolder, which can then be used for future authentication purposes.