# Difference between httpBasic() and authorizeRequest()

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spring-security

Okay, I am learning spring security and I came across some private code which has something like below configured.
`httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();`

Now, i was seeing javadocs of httpsecurity methods and came across httpBasic()

`httpSecurity.httpBasic();`

Output of both these lines are same. So, can some one help me understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### authorizeRequest()

`authorizeRequest()` used for restricting access based upon the HttpServletRequest using RequestMatcher implementations (i.e. via URL patterns).

Example Configurations:

The most basic example is to configure all URLs to require the role "ROLE_USER". The configuration below requires authentication to every URL and will grant access to both the user "admin" and "user".

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                                authorizeRequests
                                        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                        )
                        .formLogin(withDefaults());
        }
```

### httpBasic()

Configures HTTP Basic authentication. HTTP Basic authentication implementation is the simplest technique for enforcing access controls to web resources because it does not require cookies, session identifiers, or login pages. The default realm is "Spring Security Application".

Example Configurations

The example below demonstrates how to configure HTTP Basic authentication for an application.

```
@Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class HttpBasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }
 }
```

Comment: If we override "configure(HttpSecurity http)" without use httpBasic() method, It is the same when we use it, like the example you wrote.
I can't find any difference between them in practice.

please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574981/what-is-httpbasic-method-in-spring-security and help me to find the answer of my question.

Comment: The answer does not provide difference. authorizeRequest vs httpBasic both are about matchers and roles, so what is the difference? I know httpBasic sends Authentication: basic http header. Thats the basic authentication. So how does it authorizeRequest do? Is it sending http headers as well?