# spring security - cannot get to custom login

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, spring-security

Having controller, config and html:

*MvcConfig.java*:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

*SecurityConfig.java*:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
        ).logout(logout -> logout
                .permitAll()
        );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

and *login.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password
  </div>
  <div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out
  </div>
  <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div>
      <label for="username">User Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

When accessing firefox on `localhost:8080`, it redirects to `localhost:8080/login` but never gets there:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Is the reason a redirection loop? If so, hot to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I am see miss configuration to fix it you have to do some  changes according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html).

The `securityFilterChain` should have next one body:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/templates/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
        ).logout(logout -> logout
                .permitAll()
        );
       http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Also about custorm `login` page in `Spring MVC` project you have to declare a `GET` Controller that will do redirect to custom `login.html` page.

```
@Controller
class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

More details how it work and what it work so you have to check/read documentation that I give above.

Comment: Two questions: 1) I have commented `@EnableWebSecurity` at the top because I dont know what it does and everything works without it so why to have it. What does it do? 2) the authentication worked before without `http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())`, but now it has to be added, when login is customized? I was creating this learning project from `https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/` and they dont have `httpBasic` added, as is in my original post. So when to add it and when it is redundant?

Comment: I will answer with some references to others stackOverflow posts: [what-is-the-use-of-enablewebsecurity-in-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671457/what-is-the-use-of-enablewebsecurity-in-spring) and second one [httpBasic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123520/difference-between-httpbasic-and-authorizerequest) explanation on comparing topic with `authorizeRequest`. I think these 2 references will be able to answer to your questions.

Comment: 1) doesn't really shows the need of `@Enablewebsecurity` because the link answer says it merely "switch off the default web application security configuration", which is already switch off by providing `securityFilterChain` so I see no usecase for that annotation. 2) `authorizeRequest` vs `httpBasic` both are about matchers and roles, so what is the difference? I know `httpBasic` sends `Authentication: basic` http header. Thats the basic authentication. So how does it `authorizeRequest` do? Is it sending http headers as well?

Comment: About second one I pointed that post because it explain in simple words what is `httpBasic` but `authorizeRequest` is just a restriction to some paths/endpoint that you have in application. About first one it depends if it is pure `Spring Security` you have to add it to configuration but usually in `spring security starters` it does not  make sens

Comment: I need a little bit help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77392398/how-to-load-static-resources-in-thymeleaf

Comment: Hey I have made an update to current answer about help to second one, there is nothing difficult you just have to add some more paths to be also under `permitAll()`.  SOmething like next ones `.requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/templates/**").permitAll()`