# Spring Security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I wrote code, run it, but when i send request in Postman i get 403 Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD8ty.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Hul.png)
I look for all sites, but i didnt find answers  I used those links https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html

`````
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/open")
    public String open() {
        return "open url";
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String home() {
        return "home url";
    }
    @GetMapping("/secure")
    public String secure() {
        return "secure url";
    }

}
package com.example.securityspring.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .cors((cors) -> cors.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        (authorizationManagerRequestMatchers -> authorizationManagerRequestMatchers
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/open").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secure").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER"))
                ).sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}````
`````

Comment: please format correctly the images, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()) in your securityFilterChain.

You can read more about him [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574981/what-is-httpbasic-method-in-spring-security)

```
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .cors((cors) -> cors.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    (authorizationManagerRequestMatchers -> authorizationManagerRequestMatchers
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/open").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER"))
            ).sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```